# Has anyone tried BLS’ doorstep service?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, spain, vfs-global

Has anyone tried BLS' doorstep service?

I wanted to apply for Spain visa and wanted to go for doorstep service this time as I don't have enough time to visit the BLS, Delhi. So, I was wondering if it's worth it. If you have used this doorstep service can you please share your experience?